# Calculus and Matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

Suppose I have a linear operator $T: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and also suppose that it's a composition of elementary functions, so its derivative, $T'$, is reasonable easy to find.

I can represent $T$ as a matrix $[T]$ instead. Then I should be able to represent $T'$ as a matrix as well, $[T']$; I make the assumption that the derivative of a linear operator is linear, which I think is true, but I'm not sure.

Anyway, though, now I have a matrix representing the derivative of a function. Is $[T']$ called the derivative of $[T]$, i.e., did I find the derivative of a matrix? And if not, is there a way to do calculus like this with matrices?

Googling "matrix calculus" does bring some results, but I find them hard to understand, which is why I turn to you guys.

Comment: The only linear operators from $\mathbb R$ to itself are functions of the form $f(x)=rx$ for some $r\in \mathbb R$, so this isn't a very interesting case. Also, the derivative of a linear operator $T$ is just $T$ - because a derivative is just a linear approximation of a function.

Comment: Shall I just make it a linear operator in general? Even though I'm not sure I understand very well what derivatives in higher dimensional spaces really mean.

Comment: You could, but there's not very much to talk about here--the derivative of $T$ is just $T$, so we don't really bother taking derivative of linear operators.

Comment: Okay, I see. Is there a setting where it's interesting to do calculus with matrices / linear transformations?

Comment: Certainly. You could for example have a matrix-valued function.